# How did DSolve solve for the constants of integrations in this ode?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I solved this ode by hand and obtained the general solution. But not able to solve for the constants of the integrations given the initial conditions, as when I try, I get no solution.

Yet, Mathematica is able to do it, and would like to find how it did it.  The problem is from text book

[image]

Mathematica gets the correct solution.  This is what I did

```
ClearAll[y, x];
ode = y''[x] == -Exp[-2*y[x]]
(*just use one solution for now, but I tried both also*)
sol = y[x] /. First@DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So now initial conditions

```
 y[3] == 0
 y'[3] == 1
```

Need to be applied to the above solution in order to solve for `C[1],C[2]` and here is the problem. Setting up the two equations and asking `Solve` to Solve for  `C[1],C[2]`

```
eq1 = 0 == Limit[sol, x -> 3] // Simplify
eq2 = 1 == Limit[D[sol, x], x -> 3] // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {C[1], C[2]}]
{}
```

Tried Reduce, SolveAlways, FindInstance and nothing works. Unable to find solution.

But Mathematica gets the correct solution:

```
ClearAll[y, x];
ode = y''[x] == -Exp[-2*y[x]]
ic = {y[3] == 0, y'[3] == 1}
sol = DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How did Mathematica solve for the constants of integration? What method did it use?

**Update**

Figured how to solve it by hand. This looks like how `DSolve`  did it, from the Trace shown  by Michael below.

The whole idea it to solve for one constant early one (from the $y'$ and only then solve for $y$. This is easier to do by hand than program it in).

\begin{align*}
y^{\prime\prime}  & =-e^{-2y}\\
y\left(  3\right)    & =0\\
y^{\prime}\left(  3\right)    & =1
\end{align*}
Let $p=y^{\prime}$, then $y^{\prime\prime}=\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}p$. The ode becomes
$$
p\frac{dp}{dy}=-e^{-2y}
$$
This is first order ode. The solution is
\begin{equation}
p=\pm\sqrt{e^{-2y}+2c_{1}}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Taking one solution for now (same for the other), then $p=\sqrt{e^{-2y}+2c_{1}}$. But from initial conditions $p\left(  3\right)  =1,y\left(  3\right)  =0$. Hence
\begin{align*}
1  & =\sqrt{e^{-2\left(  0\right)  }+2c_{1}}\\
1  & =\sqrt{1+2c_{1}}\\
c_{1}  & =0
\end{align*}
The solution (1) becomes
\begin{align*}
p  & =\sqrt{e^{-2y}}\\
& =e^{-y}
\end{align*}
Or since $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{-y}
$$
This is first order ode whose solution is (taking one of them now)
\begin{equation}
y=\ln\left(  x+c_{2}\right)  \tag{2}
\end{equation}
But $y\left(  3\right)  =0$, hence
$$
0=\ln\left(  3+c_{2}\right)
$$
Hence $3+c_{2}=1$ or $c_{2}=-2$.  Therefore the solution (2) becomes
$$
y=\ln\left(  x-2\right)
$$

`DSolve` is very good. Without doing this, and waiting for the end to solve both constants at same time (like I was doing), it would have got into trouble too. But it is much smarter than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what `DSolve` did, but I often try `Sinc[z]` when I see `Sin[z]/z` or `Sinh[z]/z`, because it gets around the need for `Limit` near `z == 0`.  Since `C[1] == 0` is excluded as a solution in the form of the solution returned by `DSolve`, this seemed worth trying.

```
dsol = DSolve[ode, y, x]; (* get Function form *)

Solve[
 Simplify[
   {y[3], y'[3]} == {0, 1} /. Last@dsol (* N.B. *)
   ] /.
  {Sinh[z_] :> z*Sinc[I z], Coth[z_] :> Cosh[z]/(z*Sinc[I z])},
 {C[1], C[2]}]

(* {{C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> -2}}  *)
```

---

*Update*

I think `DSolve` does something like the following, based on tracing `Solve` during the computation:

1. It solves the IVP for `y'[x]` by multiplying the ODE on both sides by `y'[x]` and integrating.  It gets `1/2 y'[x]^2 == 1/2 E^(-2 y[x])`, using the ICs to eliminate a constant of integration.
2. It reduces to two equations `y'[x] == ±E^-y[x]`.
3. It then integrates these (they're separable), to get `y[x] == Log[±x + C[1]]`.
4. Again it uses the ICs to solve for `C[1]` and throw out the solution that does not satisfy the ICs.

The following shows the `Solve[]` commands. What `DSolve` is doing from step to step is just my guess. (For instance, the `Solve[]` with the long internal variable name is the equation one solves to get the constant of integration in step 1 above.)

```
Trace[
   DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x],
   s_Solve :> HoldForm[s] -> s,
   TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Solving for the constants in stages is much easier in this case, which can be verified by hand, too.

Comment: Thanks. I have feeling DSolve must have used more generic method, as it has to work for any other input? Otherwise, how would it know to do these transformation? I am also not sure why using these transformations made it solve it. I tried to use Wolfram alpha to see the steps, but it did not show these.

Comment: @Nasser I'm meant to be doing something else, but tracing Solve[] wasn't too bad. See the update I knew the original answer was not what you were looking for, but it was easy to try.

Comment: Thanks. I just figured also how to solve it by hand. I think it might be similar to what you show. I just need to type the latex and post it at the end of my question so you can check if it looks OK.

Comment: Yes, looking more at your trace, I think that is similar to what I did by hand also.  I just have to figure how to code it myself. sometimes it is easier to do something by hand than on the computer. I need to learn how to use Trace more. I am not good at it. I know you are good with Traces.