# Why is DSolve unable to solve this second order ode with initial conditions? Any workaround?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, debugging

Fyi, report to WRI as suggedted. **[CASE:4956902]**

---

This ode is similar to one [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271476/how-did-dsolve-solve-for-the-constants-of-integrations-in-this-ode) but for some reason `DSolve` could not able to solve this. This ode is from a textbook

**My question is**: What is the reason it can't solve this since it is similar to the one in the above link, and any workaround to make `DSolve` solve this one?

I solved by hand below as well. I used the Trace commands by Michael E2 from the above answer, but it did not help me figure where it went wrong and I am not good at internal tracing of Mathematica functions.

### Code

```
ClearAll[y, x];
ode = y''[x] == y'[x]*Exp[y[x]];
ic = {y[3] == 0, y'[3] == 1};
DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x]
(* {} *)
```

The solution it should have given is  `y[x]->-Log[4-x]` as shown below.

### Verification of solution

```
mysol = y -> Function[{x}, -Log[4 - x]]
ode /. mysol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ic/.mysol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Hand solution

\begin{align*}
y^{\prime\prime} &  =y^{\prime}e^{y}\\
y\left(  3\right)   &  =0\\
y^{\prime}\left(  3\right)   &  =1
\end{align*}
Let $p=y^{\prime}$, then $y^{\prime\prime}=\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}p$. The ode becomes
\begin{align*}
\frac{dp}{dy}p  & =pe^{y}\\
\frac{dp}{dy}  & =e^{y}
\end{align*}
Which has the solution
\begin{equation}
p=e^{y}+c_{1}\tag{1}%
\end{equation}
Using initial conditions given by $p\left(  3\right)  =1,y\left(  3\right)    =0$ the above becomes
$$
1=1+c_{1}
$$
Hence $c_{1}=0$ and the solution (1) simplifies to
\begin{align*}
p  & =e^{y}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}  & =e^{y}
\end{align*}
This is separable.
$$
e^{-y}dy=dx
$$
Integrating gives
\begin{equation}
-e^{-y}=x+c_{2}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
But $y\left(  3\right)  =0$, hence
$$
-1=3+c_{2}
$$
Therefore $c_{2}=-4$ and  (2) becomes
\begin{align*}
-e^{-y}  & =x-4\\
e^{-y}  & =4-x\\
-y  & =\ln\left(  4-x\right)  \\
y  & =-\ln\left(  4-x\right)
\end{align*}

### Attempt at Tracing using Michael E2's code

```
ClearAll[y,x];
ode=y''[x]==y'[x]*Exp[y[x]];
ic={y[3]==0,y'[3]==1};
Trace[DSolve[{ode,ic},y[x],x],s_Solve:>HoldForm[s]->s,TraceInternal->True]//Flatten//Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Only workaround: `ode = y''[x] == y'[x]*Exp[y[x]];
ic = {y[3] == 0, y'[3] == A};
sol = DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x]; Limit[y[x] /. First@sol, A -> 1]`.

Comment: Thanks for all the great answers, I wish I can accept both of them. Report to WRI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd report this to WRI. If buried in the `DSolve` code base is a way to solve this, then the decision tree misses it.  Otherwise, they should implement a way.  `DSolve` has a method to solve `y''[x] == F[y[x]]`. Here's is a modification of it to solve `y''[x] == F[y[x], y'[x]]` (tested only on this problem!).

I snatched the code for `y''[x] == F[y[x]]` and modified by hand.  The modifications are surround by `(**)` on either side.

```
mySpecialOrder2BVP // ClearAll;
First@DownValues@DSolve`DSolveExtendedLibraryDump`SpecialOrder2BVP /. 
  s_Symbol :> 
   With[{v = Symbol@SymbolName[s]}, 
    RuleCondition[v, ! MemberQ[Context[s], $ContextPath]]] /. 
 SpecialOrder2BVP -> mySpecialOrder2BVP
```

Edit the output above to be the following:

```
(*"
 * Solves y''[x] == F[y[x], y'[x]] if LHS is integrable w.r.t x
"*)
DownValues@mySpecialOrder2BVP = {
   HoldPattern[
     mySpecialOrder2BVP[eqn_, ycond_, yprimecond_, a_, y_, x_]] :> 
    Block[{rhs, w, res1, c, res},
     rhs = eqn[[2]] /.  (**) {y[x] | y'[x] -> w}(**);
     (res1 = 
        Quiet[Solve[ (**)
          Derivative[1][y][x] == Integrate[eqn[[2]], x](**)  + c /. 
            x -> a /. {ycond, yprimecond}, c]];
       (res1 = (**)
          Derivative[1][y][x] == 
           Integrate[eqn[[2]], x](**)  + (c /. res1[[1]]);
         res = (**)
          DSolve[res1 && ycond[[1]] == ycond[[2]], {y}, {x}]; (**)
         res /; FreeQ[res, (**)DSolve(**)]) /;
        MatchQ[res1, {{c -> m_}}] && FreeQ[res1, Integrate]) /;
      FreeQ[rhs, y | x]]
   };


mySpecialOrder2BVP[ode, Sequence @@ First@Solve[ic], 3, y, x]

(*  {{y -> Function[{x}, -Log[4 - x]]}}  *)
```

I don't have a way to hook this into `DSolve` automatically.

*Edit notice:* I neglected to mark the change from the internal `` DSolve`DSolveParser `` to `DSolve`.  `DSolveParser[]` threw a couple of `Part::partw` errors that could be ignored. Calling the top-level `DSolve` seemed the best fix for this answer. The `Condition` should therefore be `FreeQ[res, DSolve]`. It seems to me that the errors are but that arise because the internal `SpecialOrder2BVP[]` hasn't been updated to pass `DSolveParser[]` complete option value data (with the new options like `IncludeSingularSolutions`). I haven't noticed anyone reporting such a bug yet, though. (Also, I don't know why `Integrate` is called twice. It seems wasteful.)

Comment: Great response (+1)!  May I suggest that you report this issue to WRI, because you have a better understanding of the matter than I or (I surmise) the OP.  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks! I reported it, with reference to Nasser's case number and my further observations about `Part::partw` and `Integrate`. My case number: [CASE:4957084].

Answer (score 5):

With a bit of assistance, `DSolve` can obtain the desired solution.  `ode` has a first integral, which is obtained by

```
Integrate[Subtract @@ ode, x, GeneratedParameters -> C] == 0
(* -E^y[x] + C[1] + Derivative[1][y][x] == 0 *)
```

Applying the initial conditions then yields

```
Solve[% /. x -> 3 /. Rule @@@ ic, C[1]] // Flatten
(* {C[1] -> 0} *)
```

`DSolve` now obtains the desired solution

```
DSolve[{%% /. %, ic}, y[x], x] // Flatten
(* {y[x] -> -Log[4 - x]} *)
```

**Addendum**

To answer why `DSolve` fails in the question, consider

```
s = DSolveValue[{ode, First@ic}, y[x], x, , Assumptions -> C[1] ∈ Reals]
(* -Log[-(1/C[1]) + (E^(3 C[1] - x C[1]) (1 + C[1]))/C[1]] *)
```

Applying the second boundary condition then yields

```
Solve[1 == D[s, x] /. x -> 3, C[1]] // Flatten
{C[1] -> 0}
```

Of course, inserting this value of `C[1]` into `s` fails.

> > Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

On the other hand, as suggested by Mariusz Iwaniuk in a comment,

```
Limit[s, %]
(* -Log[4 - x] *)
```

does work. Apparently, `DSolve` does not try this.