# Why does DSolve spit out Part::partw warning?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, version-13.1

**Bug introduced in 13.1. and fixed in V 13.2.1**

---

Submitted to WRI. CASE  ID [**CASE:4975479**].

---

I was looking at this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274568/solve-the-differential-equations-of-r-and-%CE%B8-to-find-the-r%CE%B8).

In V 13.1 I get an internal error which the above question does not mention so I assume it is a version difference? I slightly changed the input to make it more clear:

```
ClearAll[r, x, u]
ode1 = r''[x] + r[x] * (u'[x])^2 == 0
ode2 = u''[x] * r[x] + 2 * r'[x] * u'[x] == 0
ic = {r[0] == 1, r'[0] == 0, u[0] == 0, u'[0] == 0}
```

And now

```
DSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic}, {r[x], u[x]}, x]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why this error generated? Is this a bug? I see nothing wrong with the input. Does this happen on other versions/systems?

V 13.1 on windows 10.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it in version `13.0.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (January 29, 2022)`

Comment: In v12.0.0 Windows10 `DSolve` doesn't evaluate, perhaps because `{ode1, ode2} /. x -> 0  /. (ic /. Equal -> Rule)` gives  `{r''[0] == 0, u''[0] == 0}`

Comment: Version 13.1 Windows 10 produces this error. As the same equations with NDSolve work, I think it is  a bug. Please report it to support@wolfram.com

Comment: This is a confirmed bug. Interestingly I encountered this bug about 3 months ago when solving almost the same problem (asked in Chinese community).

Comment: Fixed in 13.2.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `` DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEsDump`DSolvenOrder1NonlinearODEs `` has not been updated to pass `` DSolve`DSolveParser[] `` complete option value data (with the new options like `IncludeSingularSolutions`).

As far as I can tell, `DSolve` proceeds merrily along despite the error. All the error does is set a non-`True` value to `` DSolve`$DSolveSingularSolutions ``.

Similar issue here with another internal function: [Why is DSolve unable to solve this second order ode with initial conditions? Any workaround?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271485/why-is-dsolve-unable-to-solve-this-second-order-ode-with-initial-conditions-any/271522#271522)

FWIW, here's a general solution that `DSolve` generates internally  for `r` and `u'` (not `u`).  But `DSolve` rejects it, it seems, even though one can solve for `u` from `u'`.  The IVP cannot be solved, however.

```
sol = # /.
      r -> 
       Function[{x}, 
        Sqrt[-C[1]^2 + 4 x^2 C[2]^2 - 8 x C[2]^2 C[3] + 
         4 C[2]^2 C[3]^2]/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[2]])] /.
     u -> (Derivative[-1][v][#] + C[4] &) /.
    v -> 
     Function[{x}, (
      2 C[1] C[2])/(-C[1]^2 + 4 x^2 C[2]^2 - 8 x C[2]^2 C[3] + 
       4 C[2]^2 C[3]^2)] &;

{ode1, ode2} // sol // Simplify
(*  {True, True}  *)

u[x] // sol // Simplify
(*
1/2 (2 C[4] - Log[C[1] + 2 C[2] (x - C[3])] + 
   Log[C[1] + 2 C[2] (-x + C[3])])
*)

{r[0] == 1, r'[0] == 0, u[0] == 0, u'[0] == 0} // sol // 
  Simplify // Solve
(*  {}  *)
```

Comment: `DSolvenOrder1NonlinearODEs` looks like a typo, but if so, WRI let it slide through.

Comment: Compare with the numeric `ode1 = r''[x] + r[x]*(u'[x])^2 == 0
ode2 = u''[x]*r[x] + 2*r'[x]*u'[x] == 0
ic = {r[0] == 1, r'[0] == 0, u[0] == 0, u'[0] == 0}


sol = NDSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic}, {r[x], u[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in V 13.2.1 as this screen shot shows

[image: Mathematica graphics]